# undefined method `setup' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

After updating Active Admin from the `gregbell/active_admin` repo so it works with rails > 4.1,  I get this error when I start my rails app.

```
 undefined method `setup' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)
```

The setup method is used in the devise initalizer file in the initializer folder.

Whats causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging around I found this commit

[Make devise soft dependency](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/commit/03a95aef65dd247621489f8dd21e1be18da2dbee)

This means that I had to add devise to my own gem file. I had removed it because activeadmin installed devise as an dependency.

**Solution**

Gemfile

```
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2'
```